# Using the pip2d function in R, how do we know the correct 'order' of the vertices?

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to determine if a point is contained inside a polygon. I am using the R function, pip2d, to do it. I understand the basic principles of the function, but I am having trouble figuring out the appropriate order in which to put the vertices in my polygon matrix. Since I am going to iterate the function over a lot of data, I need to really understand this part so I don't encounter future problems.

### 1st try

This is what I did for my first try:

```
poly1 <- rbind(c(14,36), c(14,63), c(25,63), c(25,36))
points <- rbind(c(20,45), c(20,70), c(35,45), c(35,70))
pip2d(poly1, points)
```

With these coordinates, I was expecting the function to return this output: `1, -1, -1, -1`, meaning that the point (20,45) was inside the borders of the polygon.

Instead, I got this : `-1, -1, 1, -1` which didn't make any sense to me.

### 2nd try

I played around a bit with it and changed the order of the vertices, but kept the same polygon:

```
poly1 <- rbind(c(14,36), c(25,36), c(25,63), c(14,63))
points <- rbind(c(20,45), c(20,70), c(35,45), c(35,70))
pip2d(poly1, points)
```

This change gave me the expected output: `1, -1, -1, -1`.

**What's the difference between the order of the first try and the one of the second try?**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the [convention used to define polygon interior or polygon exterior](http://esri.github.io/geometry-api-java/doc/Polygon.html).
Although it's not clearly specified in `pip2d` documentation, reading the referenced articles suggests that the convention used here is the 'right hand rule'.

Follow the vertices sequence with the fingers of your right hand :

- if your thumb is pointing at you (you're turning Counter Clock Wise), what is in your hand is the interior of the polygon
- if your thumb is pointing in the opposite direction, what is in your hand is an hole not belonging to the polygon